# Nested Function not working in JavaScript (YouTube API)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I need to show a video when Launch button is clicked and when video ends it should redirect to a site.
The Problem is, video is playing onLoad. How can I play it only when button is clicked.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<a onClick="myvideo()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large big"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>LAUNCH</a>

<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

JS

```
function mySite() {
    window.open('http://www.spark2k15.com','_self');
}


// create youtube player
var player;
function myvideo() {
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'xgRbxO94GRQ',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
       event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            // alert('done');
            mySite();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't want to do that `// autoplay video` thingy you've created? Have you written that code yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, the video should not be played, as `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` seems not exposed for the api to call.

What you should do is:

1. Remove the `myvideo` function block.
2. Change the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` to `addEventListener` to the `<a>`, and create the player in the handler.

The working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c301wv/5/).

Fix HTML

```
<a id="clickPlay" href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large big"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>LAUNCH</a>

<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
// Shouldn't the api be this line? 
// Also, make sure that your function exposed for the api should be declared before api loaded.
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

JS:

```
function mySite() {
    window.open('http://www.spark2k15.com','_self');
}

// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var anchor = document.getElementById('clickPlay');
    // Only when the anchor is clicked, we create the video.
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'xgRbxO94GRQ',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    });
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {          
        // alert('done');
        mySite();
    }
}
```